# Serialized property in neo4j node

Tags: json, serialization, neo4j

I need to have serialized object as node property (string type) in neo4j using Java, do i able to apply some convertor/serializer?

I know that .NET neo clients have something like JsonConverter

Comment: Can you tell us any more about your environment? e.g are you using Spring? Are you just looking for a library like Jackson (https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson)

Comment: I'm using spring integration with Neo4J

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using SDN (and by proxy I suppose the rest of the Spring framework) then this is very easy for you. Firstly you should create a converter for your Property that will convert the data to a String (See section 7.5 of the [Spring documentation](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/validation.html)):

```
import org.springframework.core.convert.converter.Converter

public class YourPropertyTypeToStringConverter 
     implements Converter<YourPropertyType, String> {

     @Override
     public String convert(final YourPropertyType source) {
         //some code that takes your object and returns a String
     }
}
```

And another to convert it back again:

```
public class StringToYourPropertyTypeConverter 
     implements Converter<String, YourPropertyType> {

     @Override
     public YourPropertyType convert(final String source) {
         //some code that takes a String and returns an object of your type
     }
}
```

Then you should enable Spring Framework conversion by adding some configuration:

```
<bean id="conversionService"
      class="org.springframework.context.support.ConversionServiceFactoryBean">
    <property name="converters">
        <set>
            <bean class="your.package.YourPropertyTypeToStringConverter"/>
            <bean class="your.package.StringToYourPropertyTypeConverter"/>
        </set>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The in your @NodeEntity annotated class you can add a [@GraphProperty](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/neo4j/docs/current/reference/html/#) annotation to the field that requires conversion in the form:

```
@GraphProperty(propertyType = String.class)
```

Now your converter can do whatever it likes as long as you can convert in both directions, but you asked specifically for JSON, so a trivial example using Jackson.

Include Jackson in your project:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.3</version>
</dependency>
```

To convert from a Class to a String:

```
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
String json = mapper.writeValueAsString(yourObject);
```

And back again:

```
YourPropertyType deserialised = mapper.readValue(json, YourPropertyType.class);
```

Obviously lots you can configure, there some documentation on [GitHub](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind/).